# ElasticSearch bulk insert leads to WriteStateException and unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to create ~2.5 million documents in my ElasticSearch instance fails due to a: `WriteStateException`

I am using `elasticsearch-py` with the `helpers.bulk` function to index the documents. Code looks like this:

```
actions = [
    {
        "_op_type": "create",
        "_index": index_name,
        "_id": _get_id(document),
        "doc": asdict(document),
        "doc_as_upsert": False,
    }
    for document in documents
]

helpers.bulk(
    client=es_session,
    actions=actions,
    refresh=_get_refresh_setting(),
    chunk_size=chunk_size,
    request_timeout=request_timeout,
)
```

I have tried various chunk sizes between 500 and 10.000 and have also increase the request timeout up to 3600 (= 1h).

I am using ES version 7.8.1 with a single node in a Docker container. There is only once Index that is completely empty before I begin with my action. The Index was created with a mapping similar to this:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "normalizer": {
                "lowercase_unaccent_normalizer": {
                    "type": "custom", "char_filter": [], "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "identifier": {"type": "keyword"},
            "name": {"type": "keyword"},
            "vector": {"type": "dense_vector", "dims": HIDDEN_CELLS},
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the ElasticSearch log is as follows:

```
{
    "type": "server",
    "timestamp": "2020-10-28T06:39:38,320Z",
    "level": "WARN",
    "component": "o.e.i.c.IndicesClusterStateService",
    "cluster.name": "docker-cluster",
    "node.name": "elasticsearch-cb6858695-9qdh2",
    "message": "[.tasks][0] marking and sending shard failed due to [failed to create shard]",
    "cluster.uuid": "8-BFXGMcSSaBcUAvqyefbg",
    "node.id": "EplobYNeTK213O8soSVIbQ",
    "stacktrace": [
        "org.elasticsearch.gateway.WriteStateException: failed to rename tmp file to final name in the first state location /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/8TyPjAZnRM2jInEXBmWghA/0/state-0.st.tmp",
        "at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetadataStateFormat.performRenames(MetadataStateFormat.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]",
        "at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetadataStateFormat.write(MetadataStateFormat.java:245) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]",
        "at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetadataStateFormat.writeAndCleanup(MetadataStateFormat.java:185) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]",
        "at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.persistMetadata(IndexShard.java:2730) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]",
        "at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.<init>(IndexShard.java:372) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]",
        ...

        "Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/8TyPjAZnRM2jInEXBmWghA/0/_state/state-0.st.tmp -> /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/8TyPjAZnRM2jInEXBmWghA/0/_state/state-0.st: Interrupted system call",
        "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100) ~[?:?]",
        "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]",
        "at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:415) ~[?:?]",
        "at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:267) ~[?:?]",
...
```

Now, whenever I try to query ElasticSearch I get following exception:

```
> curl localhost:9200/my_index/_search
> {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503}
```

Also, checking for cluster health gives me a red status:

```
> {"cluster_name":"docker-cluster","status":"red","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":2,"active_shards":2,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":3,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":40.0}
```